# migrating a table full with data from MSSQL to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, data-migration

I'm importing data from SQL Server to mysql.

Currently I need to migrate a single a table with a simple data structure (no constraints, only values), to mysql. The table is 1.6 milion rows

What is a good way to accomplish this?

(I saw other related topics here, but don't see something that  I can work with)

Comment: Write a program that connects to SQL Server, fetches some rows, writes the INSERT queries, sends them to MySQL, clears its data structures to free up the memory, and repeats until there are no more rows to copy. 1.6 million rows is nothing, a few minutes to copy, so no need doing something complicated, just write up this program in whatever language you're most comfortable with. It won't be a lot of code.

Comment: It took me a few hours last time I tried, so wondered about other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to write a program using your favorite language to migrate the data. If you are looking for a tool to accomplish this, have a look at MySQL Migration Toolkit. It migrates data from various data sources to MySQL database.

[MySQL Migration Toolkit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use SSIS, it can connect to ODBC data destinations and might be quicker to implement than writing an application from scratch.